# Meaning: deconstruct (cooking)?

Tags: meaning

In cooking what exactly does it mean to deconstruct something?

Haven't seen this covered much in dictionaries, etc.

edit: as per @Frank's request

this is everywhere in cooking recently:

> deconstructed shortcake
>
> deconstructed tiramisu
>
> deconstructed sauce

Comment: Can you provide a sentence or quote showing the usage of the word? That would probably help.

Comment: @Frank edited - sorry it's not super specific but it's everywhere recently

Comment: I think if you want to go beyond the [dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deconstruct) of what's essentially a Lit Crit term, this is a "domain-specific" usage that should be addressed on the SE [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions) site devoted to cookery.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, please ask this question on cooking.stackexchange.com and add a link to the question on that site in this question. If you prefer not to I think I might ask there as I'd never heard of the term before you asked your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "domain-specific" terminology that should be asked on [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Your guys comments below can more than constitute an answer....

Comment: 'deconstruct' is just a fancy way of saying 'analyze'.

Comment: @Mitch you might wanna take your answers to ELL, thanks.

Comment: @user3306356 To which question there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deconstruct a dish is something of a current fad here in the UK; I put it down to the influence of the popular BBC amateur chef program 'Masterchef'.  A deconstructed tiramisu will comprise a quenelle of mascarpone, a sponge finger, a sprinkling of sugar, some grated dark bitter chocolate and, who the heck knows, a double espresso on the side.  All of this will be artfully arranged on a large plate with lots of white space.  You get all the ingredients of a tiramisu, but without putting the kitchen staff to the terrible effort of combining them into a tiramisu.

So, that's what deconstruction of a dish is all about.

You are entitled to conclude that I am not a fan of deconstructed dishes ...

Comment: Do you mean that the restaurant will provide you with the basic ingredients of a dish and you (the customer) have to put them together on your own?

Comment: That's right. In the case of a tiramisu, to continue with the example, they give you a spoon, possibly also a fork, you put the ingredients into your mouth, in whatever order and combination you desire, and masticate.  But now we're wandering well off topic for this site.  Surely there's a Stack Exchange for people who eat.  Well, I mean, for people who take a serious interest in food and cooking.

Comment: This answer is a bit of an oversimplification. Have a look at [this answer in "Seasoned Advice"](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/7751/5694) (the SE cookery site). It's more a matter of the essential elements of a dish being identified (non-essentials usually being discarded), then those essentials presented in whatever way is simplest to ensure they all contribute whatever they're supposed to to the final dish as served (that's not exactly "Here are the raw ingredients, make it yourself")."

Comment: I suppose I can see that that might catch on, you could leave out something you didn't like. I particularly dislike orange peel in desserts that I would otherwise enjoy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A quick look around the internet seems to suggest that there are two meanings to this, the first is as the answer suggests _basic components of the dish served separately on one plate_ and another is decomposition of a dish or sauce to identify the ingredients and figure out which one (or blend) causes the dish to have it's characteristic flavour.

Comment: @Frank: I think it's more a matter of saying that *sometimes* the "essential qualities" of a dish can still be implemented without necessarily joining the relevant ingredients in the way they're traditionally served. But you can only do this *after* having "deconstructed" the dish to identify those essential components of the *eating* (not the *preparation/recipe*). This may enable you to put the key ingredients back together in a much simpler way (sometimes, little more than "laying them out").

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's an interesting concept. I was just about to write _I don't suppose it works for lasagne_ and then I searched for 'deconstructed lasagne' and it obviously does, there's even pictures of deconstructed beef Wellington; at least steak & kidney pie seems to have survived intact.

Comment: @Frank: Yeah, looking at a few different "deconstructed lasagne" recipes, it does indeed seem different people have different approaches. Which I suppose comes down to them having different ideas of what *exactly* the experience of eating lasagne is supposed to be all about. Some of them have *very* different ideas to me - they seem to think you can capture the essence of lasagne in something that I'd probably call a warm pasta salad.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know I shouldn't write trivia/thanks in comments but _warm pasta salad_ made me laugh. thanks.

Comment: +1 - See also, [pretentious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pretentious) ;).

Answer (score 4):

Deconstruction in cooking is a method for taking traditional dishes and reconfiguring them to create new interpretations for modern times. This method was popularized by some of the worlds most famous chefs, most notably Thomas Keller of The French Laundry.

The interpretations can come in many forms.

http://mindofachef.tumblr.com/post/44158113422/behind-the-scenes-spain-david-chang-makes-fideos

If you look at the last picture in this series you will see strawberry shortcake deconstructed. Fresh strawberries, mint cream, and cake that was made with a CO2 can and a microwave. This is a great example of deconstruction in cooking.